# Making a preview window for the camera in an app

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

Is it possible to have a preview function within the app of what the mobile camera is seeing? Or is this option only possible to code in Eclipse or similar programs?

Using the camera component in XE5 only opens the inbuilt camera app, not displaying the view within the app..

Primarily Android..

Thanks

Comment: Not sure why the downvote, sure seems like an adequate question.

Comment: Android, iOS, or both? I know Mitov has a live video feed component, but am not certain which platforms they support.

Comment: Primarily Android for now.. Do you have any ideas if RAD studio XE5 Delphi can create apps with the same features as thosed made in Eclipse, Titanium etc? Or does it have limitations?

Comment: Does anyone know the answer?

Comment: There are limitations, but you can extend it. You have access to the source. Titanium also has limitations.

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy - you have to define procedure that will be assigning camera buffer to TImage.Bitmap. OnSampleBufferToBitmap event handler can look like:

```
procedure TForm240.SampleBufferReady(Sender: TObject; const ATime: TMediaTime);
begin
  VideoCamera.SampleBufferToBitmap(Image1.Bitmap, True);
end;
```

It is taken from official example for Video Capture:  http://sourceforge.net/p/radstudiodemos/code/HEAD/tree/branches/RadStudio_XE5_Update/FireMonkey/Delphi/VideoCaptureHD/

Tested by me and works on few devices.